# Docker api: push an image to docker hub private repository

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, dockerhub, docker-registry

I can create a docker registry on 5000 port mapped to 5000 port on my local system. docker configuration file changed to `--insecure-registry localhost:5000` to make the connection insecure. How can I push images to my private repo using docker api command.

Answer (score 1):

For API I guess you can use this

Push an image on the registry
    POST /images/(name)/push

Example request:

```
POST /images/registry.acme.com:5000/test/push HTTP/1.1
Query Parameters:
```

tag – The tag to associate with the image on the registry. This is optional.

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.19/

Comment: I have edited the answer but i think its fairly straight forward with api without even having to tag before hand